# Legendre Polynomials Integrals for Laplace Solutions

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, linear-systems, spherical-harmonics

I know how to normalize Legendre polynomials, but I have a sphere with 0 to pi/3 boundaries where the potential is $V$, otherwise zero. For normalization it is -1 to 1, what changes with different boundaries?

Is there a trick to find the coefficients $A$ and $B$ under different boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

The *completeness* of the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthonormality_and_completeness) $P_n(\cos\theta)$ on the interval $0\le\theta\le\pi$ means that a (possibly infinite) linear combination of them can represent *any* function $V(a, \theta)$.

Their *orthonormality* lets you figure out which linear combination to use.

Comment: How do I choose any from that "infinite" linear combinations?

Comment: I haven’t tried doing your particular problem. In general, you may need *all* of them, with $n$ from $0$ to $\infty$. In other words, the solution may be an infinite series. Assume that it is.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I expanded my coefficients they go up to l=3. It is easy when your boundaries/potentials have some sort of symmetry, but for my case it is not. The V potential part is covering only between 0 to pi/3 surface area of the sphere. In this case what changes, not just talking about legendre polynomial wise. That I do not understand.

Comment: I don’t think they stop at 3.

Comment: You end up doing an integral from $0$ to $\pi$, but the part of the integral from $\pi/3$ to $\pi$ is zero because the potential is zero over that range.

Comment: Since you are new to the site, you may not be aware that we don’t provide complete solutions to homework-like problems such as this one.

Comment: You may want to review finding the Fourier series for a step function (say, zero from $-\pi$ to $0$ and one from $0$ to $\pi$), which is an analogous computation using a different set of orthonormal functions to make a discontinuous function.

Comment: yeah I know, I am not asking for a solution, I just want to understand.